# Chromium on Raspberry Pi breaking keyboard input

Tags: chromium, raspberry-pi2

I have a couple of older printers (a Brother and an HP all-in-one) that I want to run as wireless and cloud-based printers.  To do so, I bought a Raspberry Pi 2 and set it up as a headless print server following some online tutorials.  Both of the printers are accessible wirelessly from my home network, but because my primary computer is a Chromebook and I use Android phones and tablets, the only good way I've found to print to them is using Google Cloud Print.

To do this, I downloaded Chromium onto the Raspberry Pi and signed in using my gmail account.  This kind of worked for a few months, but the cloud connection would go down after a few days and I'd have to reboot the Raspberry Pi to get it back (there was probably a better way, but, since it was headless, it just seemed easier to reboot).

Eventually, I got tired of rebooting the Raspberry Pi and I read something on the Internet about upgrading my software to get new versions of the OS and of Chromium.  Unfortunately, since doing so, I've been having problems.

Since I'm running headless, my primary means of connecting are via ssh and vnc connections from my Chromebook.  ssh is fine, but I can't run Chromium on the Raspberry Pi via ssh (at one time, I found a tutorial on how to do this, but it has since been taken down and I think Google nixed the support for that somewhere along the line).

To start Chromium, I log with a vnc connection.  When I log on the first time after a reboot (or after restarting the vnc server), everything works fine.  I can use, for instance, the word processor or terminal available through the GUI.  All is well.  However, if I start Chromium, all of the sudden nothing will accept keyboard input.  It is *almost* as if there is no keyboard connected at all at this point.  Mouse input still works fine and I can open and close programs to my heart's content.  Closing Chromium doesn't fix the problem.  Closing the vnc connection from the client and logging back in doesn't fix the problem.  Restarting the vnc server *does* fix it until I start Chromium again.

I say "almost" above because, even though pressing keys on the keyboard don't appear to do anything, the cursor (especially visible in the terminal window) *does* flicker with each key press as it would if I were typing actual text.

I've searched for this issue on Google, but my search has turned up very little.  There were some lubuntu posts about possibly not using ibus, but, from what I can tell, that is not relevant to my situation.  At least, I couldn't find anything ibus in ps and I couldn't find any options in the GUI preferences.

My Raspberry Pi is running what I believe is the latest version of Raspbian (I updated/upgraded again last night to be sure):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.21-v7+ #911 SMP Thu Sep 15 14:22:38 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

It's running TightVNC with the following command-line options:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ps aux | grep vnc
pi       13537  0.0  2.2  91556 22584 ?        S    01:05   0:27 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop X -auth /home/pi/.Xauthority -geometry 1368x768 -depth 24 -rfbwait 120000 -rfbauth /home/pi/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5901 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/,/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/ -co /etc/X11/rgb
```

Chromium's chrome://help About section says "Version 51.0.2704.91 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 8.0".

Beyond that, I don't know what other software/versions would be relevant, but if anyone can think of anything else that would be helpful, I can update this description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the 4.4.38 version of Raspberry Pi 3, which is the newest, and the newest `chromium-browser (v.51)`. Although I am using a mouse and screen, I'm getting keyboard error messages, and other messages, and browser is hanging in some cases. I pretty quickly see the following errors on console after starting chromium:

```
[2530:2530:0217/142822:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(334)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[75:75:0217/142957:ERROR:PlatformKeyboardEvent.cpp(117)] Not implemented reached in static PlatformEvent::Modifiers blink::PlatformKeyboardEvent::getCurrentModifierState()
```

After asking on the raspberrypi.org forum, it was suggested that I wait for the next version of Chromium. It looks pretty sure that there is an i/o error between mouse and keyboard controls and chromium, and appears quite similar to your issue.

Comment: This should actually go as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: While I don't disagree that this should probably be a comment rather than an answer, in the end, waiting for the next version of Chromium and upgrading solved the problem, which, I suppose, makes this the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Through trial and error, I've discovered that the Chromium keyboard/RDP issue seems to be related to particular extensions on my profile.

To verify this, try running Chromium with --disable-extensions.

The particular extensions/apps I've found to be problematic are:

- Google Play Music
- Plex

As soon as I disable these, keyboard starts working again. Does this help?

Comment: you can't comment, so don't.

Answer (score 0):

(I do not have the necessary 50 points, so I cannot comment, only as a solution,  which in this case is not true, since I also did not find it yet.)

I have the exact same problem with a Pi 3, but in my case when remotely connected with xrdp (w/ Windows Remote Desktop).
I believe the symptoms appeared after an update-upgrade session. My current version:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.38-v7+ #938 SMP Thu Dec 15 15:22:21 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I originally only wanted to change the keyboard-layout to German, and from what I understood until now is that through xrdp it is not possible, unless you define your keyboard layout completely manually, see:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=265100
http://cloclotron.net/xrdp_keyboard_layout_workaround.html

As soon as I open Chromium, I see the same behaviour as you, if I close it, everything is back  to normal. If working on a directly connected monitor with kexboard plugged in, I experience no problems.