# chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, command-line-interface, chromium

Here is a CLI command for chromium-browser

`chromium-browser --kiosk --start-fullscreen /home/lando2319/WeatherWindow/home.html`

This is actually opening the browser just fine, but it leaves me with the command

```
[5488:5488:0520/174814.193710:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
```

Unfortunately this just hangs, and eventually when I press control c, it escapes the window.

Do you know how I can open this window and not be held hostage by this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--disable-extensions` does the job

One of the, 'related questions', was "Chromium on Raspberry Pi breaking keyboard input", this lead me to this flag which got rid of the error, and opened the file as expected. Thanks Stackoverflow, this 'related question' was perfect.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42319666/2066855

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help me

Comment: Does not fix it.